# TS transpiled cloud tasks fail because @google-cloud/functions-framework cannot be found

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, transpiler

I have a very basic test cloud function in typescript

```
import { HttpFunction } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework'
import { Request, Response } from 'express' export

const testFuncHandler: HttpFunction = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {...}
```

I tried to run it locally, but when I actually build the function to JS, it tries to load the functions-framework like the following. This is from the JS

```
functions_framework_1.default.http('testFuncHandler', testFuncHandler_1.testFuncHandler);
```

The `.default` is undefined which causes the function to fail. But if I manually remove the `.default`, things actually work. **Was wondering if I am importing things wrong? Or is it a TS config issue?**

Here is my ts config btw thanks in advance :)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Are you facing issue with `js` or `ts`? if it is `js` can you share the `js` code, just wanted to know how you are importing `@google-cloud/firebase-frameworks`